# Haskell - Understanding where and pattern matching

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching

Im trying to create a sum function in haskell. I'm doing this to get more familiar with the language. I've defined it as so:

```
mysum :: [Integer] -> Integer
mysum lst = sm lst
  where 
    sm :: [Integer] -> Integer
    sm lst [] = 0
    sm lst [x:xs]=
      x + sm xs
```

The idea was to return the value of the head of the list, + the tail fed back into the function. I recall doing something similar in F#, but i simply cant get it to work in haskell.

```
The error im getting is:
sum.hs:5:5: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer’
                  with actual type ‘[[Integer]] -> Integer’
    • The equation(s) for ‘sm’ have two arguments,
      but its type ‘[Integer] -> Integer’ has only one
      In an equation for ‘mysum’:
          mysum lst
            = sm lst
            where
                sm :: [Integer] -> Integer
                sm lst [] = 0
                sm lst [x : xs] = x + sm xs
  |
5 |     sm lst [] = 0
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sm :: [Integer] -> Integer
   -- ^^^^^^^^^ one argument
sm lst [] = ...
-- ^^^ ^^ two arguments
sm lst [x:xs]= ...
-- ^^^ ^^^^^^ two arguments
```

You need to remove `lst`, and only pattern match on the other argument.

Further, `(x:xs)` does not use square brackets. The pattern `[x:xs]` matches a single-element list, where the element is a non empty list `x:xs` -- you don't want to match a list-of-lists.

A possible fix is therefore:

```
mysum :: [Integer] -> Integer
mysum lst = sm lst
  where 
  sm :: [Integer] -> Integer
  sm [] = 0
  sm (x : xs) = x + sm xs
```

There is a redundancy above: `mysum` and `sm` do the same thing! So, we can remove the auxiliary definition.

```
mysum :: [Integer] -> Integer
mysum []       = 0
musum (x : xs) = x + mysum xs
```